# Faster Importing of CVS files to Mysql on MAMP Pro

Tags: magento, import-from-csv

I am totally new to this but i am going to give it a try. So here it goes. I am importing some CVS files in to Mysql using Import all stock products under Import/export of System on Magento.

The original CSV has 160000 lines so broke down the CSV to 80 files and am importing one CSV file at a time but still its too slow. Is there any way that I import these files faster. I know there are all amazing ways through SSh ...but I am really not that good at using it. to make thing a little bit more clear I am using a MacPro 8 Core with 8g rom but still things are so slow. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have CVS and CSV mixed up.  Do you mean comma separated values.  You may want to post this to MySQL group.